# Can every closed curve be modified in the following way to produce a simple closed curve?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Is there a sequence of the following operation that change a closed curve with finite number of self-intersections to a simple closed curve?

Also, every self-intersection differs at least $\epsilon$ in distance. The curve never pass though the same point 3 times.

If there is a intersection that locally looks like

> ```
> a b
>  x
> c d
> ```

we can change it to one of the following

> ```
> a b
>  =
> c d
>
> a b
>  ||      
> c d
> ```

If the answer is different on different spaces, I'm interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

From some example I tried, it seems one of the move can create 2 closed curves, but not both.

Edit:
I don't know how to capture the notion of the curves. I'm wondering about this because I draw some closed curve on a notebook, and figured I can erase a intersection and connect in the above way, and eventually it become a simple closed curve.

Just assume this curve is well behaved enough that I can draw on a notebook.

Comment: What's your definition of curve a $C^0$ path, $C^1$ or $C^\infty$? I ask because I'm skeptical something like this would be able to smooth out a closed Peano Curve.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that there are only finitely many self-intersection points, or at least that every self-intersection has a finite minimal distance from all other self-intersections?

Comment: @Jacob You can pick the one that behave the best. $C^\infty$?

Comment: @Henning yes, there are only finite many self-intersections, I will fix my question.

Comment: @Jacob, I don't think even $C^\infty$ is enough to make this well-defined. Consider a curve that behaves as $t\mapsto(t,e^{-1/t^2}\sin(2\pi/t))$ near $t=0$ (which ought to be smooth) and later passes through the origin along the $x$ axis. The self-intersection at (0,0) does not look like the OP's assumption locally.

Comment: @Henning, I agree. The assumption that the injectivity fails for only finitely many $t$ is needed.

Comment: Works for [nodes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Crunode.html). How about [tacnodes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tacnode.html)?

Comment: Perhaps something like the Reidemeister moves is what you are looking for:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move

Comment: The question "Can any closed curve be modified in the following way to produce a simple closed curve?" could be construed as meaning "Is there any closed curve that can be be modified in the following way to produce a simple closed curve?", _or_ it could be construed as meaning "Is it the case that any closed curve (no matter which one) can be modified in the following way to produce a simple closed curve?".  Those are two quite different things! If the second is meant, then just changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it.

Comment: @Michael thx, fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I got this.

Parametrize the curve as f(t) = (x,y). Pick any intersection, mark 4 local points a,b,c,d, such that it looks like

> ```
> a c
>  x
> b d
> ```

and $f(t_a)=a, f(t_b)=b, f(t_c)=c, f(t_d)=d$. such that 
$t_a<t_b<t_c<t_d$

I claim the following would not make two closed curves.

> ```
> a c
>  =
> b d
> ```

The a,b,c,d divide the curve into 4 pieces. $ab, bc, cd, da$. Where $xy$ is the piece of curve $\{f(t)|t\in[t_x,t_y]\}$, where $f(t_x) = x$ and $f(t_y)=y$.

This movement only change two pieces. $ab$ to $ac$, $cd$ to $bd$. $bc$, $ad$ are not changes. Therefore if we travel though a, we will get $acbd$,

Comment: Expressed in simpler terms: If $P$ is a transversal self-intersection of a closed curve $\gamma\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ then you can always apply one of the proposed moves, which leaves a closed curve $\gamma'$ with one self-intersection less.